# How do I get name of the current Whatsapp window's title bar in Accessibility Service?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I am working on an accessibility service for Whatsapp. Whenever user presses the input box, I want to know the current title bar which usually has recipient whatsapp user or name of the whatsapp group:

[image]

I am interested in getting that string `Test User`

Here is my xml:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```

Here is my code:

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    final int eventType = event.getEventType();
    String eventText = null;
    switch(eventType) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            eventText = "Clicked: ";
            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            eventText = "Focused: ";
            break;
    }
    eventText = eventText + event.getContentDescription();
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: " + eventText);
    if (eventText.toLowerCase().contains("type a message")) {
        // access the title bar name/string here
    }
}
```

I tried getting current window or parent window and checking its title, both seem to be null:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo currentNode = event.getSource();
AccessibilityNodeInfo parentNode = nodeInfo.getParent();
AccessibilityWindowInfo currentWindow = currentNode.getWindow();
AccessibilityWindowInfo parentWindow = parentNode.getWindow();
// currentWindow.getTitle();
// parentWindow.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library to help with working on things using AccessibilityNodeInfos and other Android Accessibility APIs.  It's almost done, needs documented.  But, using this library you would accomplish this like this:

Within your main service (to allow access to the root accessibility node), do something like this.

```
A11yNodeInfo nodeInfo = A11yNodeInfo.wrap(getRootInActiveWindow());

A11yNodeInfo result = nodeInfo.visit(new A11yNodeInfo.OnVisitListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onVisit(A11yNodeInfo nodeInfo) {
       A11yNodeInfoMatcher matcher = new A11yNodeInfoMatcher();
       //Add properties to the matcher as needed.  I'm just guessing here!

       return matcher.matches(nodeInfo);
   }
});
```

If you want to explore the accessibility properties of that element, you can also just print out the entire Accessibility tree:

```
Log.d("Tag", A11yNodeInfo.wrap(getRootInActiveWindow).toViewHeirarchy());
```

https://github.com/chriscm2006/Android-Accessibility-Utilities

Comment: I think you forgot to link to your library

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

try
{
 List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/conversation_contact_name");

 if (findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() > 0)
 {
  AccessibilityNodeInfo parent = (AccessibilityNodeInfo) findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(0);

  String contactName = parent.getText().toString();

  if (contactName != null && !contactName.isEmpty()) // do your stuff here, contactName contains the chat contact name!

 }
}
catch(Exception contactName) {}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
/>
```

My onServiceConnected method:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected()
{
 AccessibilityServiceInfo info=getServiceInfo();
 info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
 this.setServiceInfo(info);
}
```